# What is a Bernoulli random variable?

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, error-function

I have the following question which I will first describe by my current understanding of binomial distribution / Bernoulli random variable.

(1) The coin has two sides, 0 or 1. The outcome of flipping the coin follows a binomial distribution law and so the coin is a Bernoulli random variable.

And so it is within a set of independent coins. Flipping 3 independent coins 3 times, leading results such as `[[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]` allows to compute three distinct error bars on the "true" value of each coin variable (which should be 0.5, and even though in this example we would need more coinflips).

So now, my problem.

(2) I have one sample which can be 0 or 1. There is no way to "flip" the sample here, it is 0 or 1 and this 0 or 1 is the true value of the sample.

I do 3 predictions on this sample, yielding `[0,1,1]`. And so I can do with a set of independent samples each following the same rule, so yielding `[[0,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]`.

And my question:

Are (1) and (2) the same thing? More precisely, is the sample a random Bernoulli variable as the coin is? And if so, can I compute the same error based on `sqrt(P(1-P)/N)` with `P = predtrue/predfalse`.

If I am out of the Bernoulli frame for (2), how to calculate an error for those prediction?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I may be missing something, but is there more to the question than word play?

Comment: No lol I am serious. Maybe it is trivial and I am just thinking too much so let me know. I am not a math guy at all, and the coin example and characteristics for this does not sound exactly the same than my samples to me. Well the coin can be one side or the other, my sample can be only one side or the other. That is what I question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution Maybe this will help.

Comment: How do you do a prediction on a sample? What does that mean? Why is the prediction sometimes $0$ and sometimes $1,$ even though the sample has not changed?

Comment: The prediction is the output of a logistic binary classifier (Neural Net) which I convert to binary decision. I stack different models to get a set of decision for a given sample, before averaging and ideally computing the error on the averaged decision. So depending on the model, the prediction can be 0 or 1, for the same sample. @herb thanks, I have been looking at wikipedia... on that same page they take the coin as example, and I already explained what I think to be a difference in my case.

Comment: In general you can't make a prediction on the basis of one flip.  The sample variance is infinite.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this. But once again: the coinflip experiment can lead to two outcomes that effectively exists: one side or the other. In my sample prediction, it can lead to two outcomes which includes only one with real existence. That is from this difference that I wonder if my sample can be considered as a Bernouilli random variable or not. And as I mentioned, there is not a single prediction, but a set of predicted labels (0 or 1) for one sample.